# Do we know who graduated from the University of Mexico in the 1700s?

Tags: 18th-century, colonial-america, education, mexico

The [Royal and Pontifical University of Mexico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_and_Pontifical_University_of_Mexico) was the country's first and foremost university in the colonial period. According to George I. Sánchez, by 1776 it had awarded 29,882 bachelor's and 1,162 graduate degrees.

Has any list or index of those graduates been compiled?

I'd like to determine whether the secular priest Agustín Fernández de San Vicente studied there (presumably in theology or canon law) in the late 1700s.  The historical archive of the successor institution, UNAM, doesn't go back into the colonial period. I searched the finding guide for the Archive of the Nation without finding an individual record mentioning his graduation.

I will accept an answer either about him specifically or on the broader question about a list of graduates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing yet on Fernández, but the records of enrollments and degrees of the University are in the 574 volumes (!) of the "Universidad" section, 1553-1863, in the "Colecciones Novohispanas" of the [Archivo General de la Nación](http://www.agn.gob.mx/).